# Writing test for the JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this simple middle layer code which will be called by someone and it  is calling some other api which is returning Promise

```
function getSomething() {
  return api.fetchSomething()
    .then(response => response)
}
```

To test this I wrote this test which is passing.

```
it('should make a call to api method ', () => {
        const someResponse = {};
        const fetchSomethingStub = sandbox.stub(api, 'fetchSomething').returns(Promise.resolve(someResponse));
        const someResult = getSomething();

        someResult.then((result) => {
            expect(fetchSomethingStub ).to.have.callCount(1);
            expect(result).to.eventually.equal(someResponse);
        });
    });
```

But since my `api.fetchSomething()` can return reject too I changed the stub to return `Promise.reject` but test is passing but with message `(node:14688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): [object Object]`. Is that mean I have to have `catch` block in this layer to.? I am planning to just pass on the value from api. Also I am doing test correctly for promise. Any suggestion with resource to look for Promise test with mocha is appreciated.

Comment: The `.then(response => response)` part is pointless. Omit it.

Comment: @Bergi is that also mean  both resolve and reject will be pass back tot he claler and that elimiate the way to need for test?

Comment: Yes, both fulfillment and rejection would be passed through directly. If you are already testing `api.fetchSomething()`, then testing `getSomething()` might be useless indeed (though an assertion that they do the same could be nice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So fundamentally you have an unhandled exception in this code. If you really want to test the behavior in the rejection case, then yes, you'll need a test that has a `.catch` handler. If the promise is rejected, the `.then` handler is never called so your asserts won't happen.

The other thing you can do is change this line:

```
    someResult.then((result) => {
```

to

```
    return someResult.then((result) => {
```

This returns the promise back out to the Mocha runner and lets it properly detect a failed test where the promise was rejected unexpectedly.

Without it you also have a synchronization bug in your test - Mocha doesn't know to wait for async stuff to finish before reporting the results. Returning the promise hooks you correctly into the test runner & result reporting.

Comment: Technically I believe, you can actually handle the error with a function in the thenable: .then((res) => {}, (rej) => {}), but this is discouraged for multiple reasons. Catch is definitely how you want to handle this; agreed.

Comment: @thesublimeobject No, it's not discouraged, have a look at the [difference between `.then(…).catch(…)` and `.then(…, …)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572). If your test wants to distinguish fulfilments from rejections, you should use `then` with two callbacks.